# Sankey Diagram - Make unclick other nodes/link after click a node/line

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I've tried to click on node/link to keep the highlight node/link on Sankey Diagram via option: *(code that is relevant has a comment in front of it)*

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['sankey']});      
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addRows([
        [ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
        [ 'A', 'Y', 7 ],
        [ 'A', 'Z', 6 ],
        [ 'B', 'X', 2 ],
        [ 'B', 'Y', 9 ],
        [ 'B', 'Z', 4 ]
    ]);
             
    // Sets chart options.
    var options = {
        width: 600,
        // The specific block of code I am talking about.
        sankey: {
            node: {
              interactivity: true
            },
            link: {
             interactivity: true
            }
        }
    };

    // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new        
    google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="sankey_basic" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

For now, when I click on the link then click on the node, it still keep highlight on link. I want to remove highlight other node/link when click on a node/link.

Comment: there aren't any config options you can set for this functionality -- there is a chart method --> `setSelection` -- but it only works with links, node selections cannot be changed or cleared manually...

Comment: @WhiteHat may be I need change to other library charts. thank you.